# Compiling with autotools: Retroactively change configure flags

Tags: compilation, autotools, configure

Say I have compiled a project (not my own) with autotools and passed some flags to configure. Now I want to compile this same project again, but with slightly different configure flags. Is there a way to tell the configure script to use the old flags, but update them with some additional ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would love to see an easier approach, but to simply add flags you can do:

```
sed -i '/^ac_configure_extra_args=/s/$/--new-flag --other-flag/' config.status
./config.status --recheck
```

Normally, I manually edit `config.status` to do this, and not all `sed` support `-i`, but you get the idea.  Change the original flags as they are defined in `config.status` to be the flags you want.

Another option is to cut-n-paste the original configure invocation out of the top of `config.log` and edit it.

Comment: Great! Since I don't need to script it, I'll stick with the manual editing of config.status. Thanks!